# Read all bytes from a file in c

Tags: c, windows, file, stat

I'm trying to read bytes from a file, but the size is corrupt. When debugging I can see the value of `st.st_size`, but I can't read the value of `size`.

```
int main(void)
{
    FILE* oud;
    struct stat st;
    _off_t size;
    unsigned* bytes;
    char const path[] = "C:\\Users\\Ruben\\Documents\\test.txt";
    errno_t error;

    if ((error  = fopen_s(&oud, path, "rb" )) != NULL)
        return -1;

    stat(path, &st);
    size = st.st_size;
    bytes = (unsigned*)malloc(size);
    fread(bytes, 1, size, oud);
    fclose(oud);

    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Are you debugging a release-mode executable by any chance? Can you `printf` the size and see what you get?

Comment: Since you have the file itself, how big does the OS say the file is (via Windows Explorer or Cmd Prompt "dir").  How big does `stat` say it is?  How many bytes can you read?   Do any of these numbers match each other and make sense?

Comment: Shouldn't `bytes` be `unsigned char*`?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using a loop and iterating over the file byte per byte, checking for the EOF char. Once you find it, you now know the real size of your file and can read it appropriately from the start, putting it in a buffer or otherwise.